# USE_L10N deprecated, but it disables DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS when removed

Tags: django, django-settings

*there's an expanded version of the accepted correct answer in my update to this question below*

Have I found a bug in Django?

The config setting `USE_L10N` is [deprecated since 4.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#use-l10n) and scheduled for removal in 5.0. However, the [documentation of `forms.DateField` for 5.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/forms/fields/#datefield)  still states

> If no input_formats argument is provided, the default input formats are taken from the active locale format DATE_INPUT_FORMATS key, or from DATE_INPUT_FORMATS if localization is disabled.

Which begs the question, how does one disable localisation and enable the DATE_INPUT_FORMATS setting once `USE_L10N = False` is not longer possible?

I don't want to upgrade to 5.0 yet, so I cannot easily test this. I have established that on 4.2, if I comment out the deprecated `USE_L10N = False` in my settings.py, then `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` ceases to be honoured.

**Update, after lucutzu33's answer** (which works with Django 4.2.)

I found it extremely non-intuitive to put something that has global effects into one arbitrary app's tree, and one doesn't have to...

settings.py

```
# USE_L10N = False      # deprecated -> removed
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-GB'
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = ['formats',] # <project>/formats, because this has global effect
```

So, create `<project>/formats`, `project/formats/en_GB`,  `<project>/formats/__init__.py`, `project/formats/en_GB/__init__.py`

Then edit `project/formats/en_GB/formats.py` to contain the desired overrides to Django defaults. See [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#format-module-path)

```
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'd/m/y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    '%d/%m/%y', '%d/%m/%Y',             # '25/10/06', '25/10/2006',
    '%d.%m.%Y', '%d.%m.%y',             # Germany, other EU use dots
    '%Y-%m-%d',                         # ISO yyyy-mm-dd
    # etc
]
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',     # '2006-10-25 14:30:59'
    # and variants,
    '%Y-%m-%d',              # '2006-10-25'
    '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S',     # '25/10/2006 14:30:59'
    # and variants...
]
```

(This content was previously in `settings.py` and activated by `USE_L10N=True`, so cut it from there and paste it here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a late response, but I have found a solution:

Copy the formats.py file you want to in your app's directory.
The path should look like `<your_project>/<your_app>/formats/ro/formats.py`

then in `settings.py` you can set:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ro-RO'
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = ['yourapp.formats',]
```

Comment: Late answers are the best! Many thanks. I'm now free to update to Django 5 without any (known) impediments.