# Django DATE and DATETIME settings have no effect since USE_L10N was deprecated

Tags: django

Since 5.0 `USE_L10N` settings was DEPRECATED and is always `True`.

Now settings like `DATE_FORMAT`, `DATETIME_FORMAT`, `DATE_FORMAT_INPUTS` etc.. don't work because as per documentation:

> Note that the locale-dictated format has higher precedence and will be
> applied instead.
> But now locale-dictated formats are always enabled.

A fix I've found is to copy the `formats.py` file you want to in your app's directory. The path should look like `<your_project>/<your_app>/formats/ro/formats.py`

then in settings.py you can set:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ro-RO'
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = ['yourapp.formats',]
```

But why have those settings anymore? Is there any way in which you can still use those settings?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my [expanded question + answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77654801/use-l10n-deprecated-but-it-disables-datetime-input-formats-when-removed) based on what you found out may help.

I think  you may have found a documentation error in the Django 5.0 docs, in that they didn't delete settings documentation from 4.2 which is no longer valid in 5.0.

The new way seems to be that you have to have a `FORMAT_MODULE_PATH` in order to override these things in a much more specific way which can be per-app and per-language. However it doesn't *have* to be per-app. You can put the `formats` folder/module in your project directory and import it with `FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = ['formats',]`

And I guess that if you want to write code that is compatible across this divide you can always leave them in `settings.py`, import settings in `formats.py` and

```
from django.conf import settings

DATE_FORMAT = settings.DATE_FORMAT
```

(I haven't tested this but can't imagine why it wouldn't work)